# async method chaining in express.js

Tags: node.js, express, axios, nodemailer

i couldnt async chaining in expressjs. The first method(getUser) is working fine and returns value properly. The second method (sendmail) is working fine (mail is sent) but it returns always `undefined`. `mailResponse` value in app.js always returns undefined.

If it wasn't running, the inside of the method shouldn't have worked either, but everything works fine except `return` statement. What is the wrong part?

this is my axios method;

```
const axios = require('axios');

const getUser = async (id) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get('xxxxxx', {
          params: {
            id: id
          }
        });
        return response.data[0];
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

module.exports = getUser;
```

sendmail method;

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'youremail@gmail.com',
    pass: 'yourpassword'
  }
});

var mailOptions = {
  from: 'youremail@gmail.com',
  to: 'myfriend@yahoo.com',
  subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
  text: 'That was easy!'
};

const sendMail = async (data) => {
    email.send(mailOptions).then(() =>{         
        console.log("email has been sent!");
        return true;
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
        return false;
      });
}

module.exports = sendMail;
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const getUser = require('./fetchData');
const sendMail = require('./sendMail');
let userid = '';
let fetchedData = null;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('server is running');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('App is listening');
});

app.get('/send', (req, res) => {
    userid = req.query.userid;
    
    if(!userid){
        res.status(404).send('Sorry, cant find that');
    } else {
       getUser(userid).then(axiosResponse => {
            console.log("axiosResponse => ", axiosResponse);
            fetchedData = axiosResponse;
            
            sendMail(fetchedData);
            
        }).then(mailResponse => {
            console.log("express mail response => ", mailResponse);
            res.send(mailResponse);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest issue I can see from your existing code is you're not returning anything in your `then` methods. That being said, I think you'll gain a lot my clarity by consistently using async/await rather than mixing it with Promise syntax:

```js
// sendMail rewrite
const sendMail = async (data) => {
  try {
    await email.send(mailOptions);
    return true;
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
    return false;
  }  
}

// get 'send' rewrite
app.get('/send', async (req, res) => {
  const userid = req.query.userid;
  
  if (!userid) {
    res.status(404).send('Sorry, cant find that');
    return;
  }
  
  try {
    const axiosResponse = await getUser(userid);
    console.log("axiosResponse => ", axiosResponse);
    const mailResponse = await sendMail(axiosResponse);
    console.log("express mail response => ", mailResponse);
    res.send(mailResponse);
  } catch(err) {
    // Do something with any errors here
  }
});
```

Comment: I edited my code based what you wrote. It works. Thank you so much!